# Automatically replace html-tags by "<br>"

Tags: php, html, replace

I'm looking for a way to replace html-tags by `<br>`.

The function `str_replace` won't work, because i don't know the attributes of the tags.

The input string could look like this (e. g.):

```
$str = "line one<p class='one'>line two</p>line three<p/>line four</p>line five<br> line six<br /><p>line eight</p>";
```

It should be convertet to:

```
$str = "line one<br>line two<br>line three<br>line four<br>line five<br>line six<br>line eight";
```

The tags I want to convert are `<p ....>`, `<br ... >`, also `<div ....>`

What's the best way to do this?

I have no idea how to replace patterns.

Comment: DOMDocument traversal is the right solution to this

Comment: You'll need to parse out the DOM (probably using DOMDocument) and work with it once it's constructed from the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty regex would be

`$str = preg_replace('#<.*?>#', '<br />', $str);`

That will replace all tags with break tags, and will not remove duplicates. If you want to do that, you can go one step further and replace multiple instances with one. The below also adds the qualifier that only p br and div tags should be replaced.

```
$str = preg_replace('#</{0,1}[p|br|div].*?>#', '<br />', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#(<br />)+#', '<br />', $str);`
```

The better solution would be to parse the DOM as others have said, but if you want something quick and easy this is it.

Comment: i have nothing else than this html-tags, so it's okay for me - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str= "line one<p class='one'>line two</p>line three<p/>line four</p>line five<br> line six<br /><p>line eight</p>";
$str= preg_replace("/<p[^>]*?>/", "<br />", $str);
$str= str_replace("</p>", "<br />", $str);
echo $str= str_replace("<br /><br />", "<br />", $str);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should write this

```
$str= "line one<p class='one'>line two</p>line three<p/>line four</p>line five<br> line six<br /><p>line eight</p>";
$str = preg_replace('#</{0,1}[p|br|div].*?>#', '<br />', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#(<br />)+#', '<br />', $str);`
$str= str_replace("</p>", "<br />", $str);
echo $str= str_replace("<br /><br />", "<br />", $str);
```

Comment: The two str_replace lines you added after my answer above are not necessary since no </p> tags will remain nor will any duplicate <br /> tags.